# Heroku java server crash

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, heroku

I've mad a java project which work fine in eclipse and I want to store it on heroku. Followed the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#tracking-your-app-in-git). I updated the pom dependencies, pushed the project and got build succeeded indication, but while trying to use the heroku ps command I got a server crashed error says that it couldn't find my main class. Here's the log error:

```
2015-10-22T17:32:32.303445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `j
ava -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp bin:target/dependency/* ServerMain`
2015-10-22T17:32:34.107670+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults
based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2015-10-22T17:32:34.118434+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx38
4m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2015-10-22T17:32:34.482566+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main
class ServerMain
2015-10-22T17:32:35.596974+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-10-22T17:32:35.582629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

My Procfile looks like this:`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp bin:target/dependency/* ServerMain`
All my java classes are in the bin folder and the ServerMain file contains a main function. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your `ServerMain` exist in the root package, or should it be `com.myapp.ServerMain` (or something)?

Comment: Yea it's in my root package

Comment: what happens when you run `heroku run ls bin/ServerMain.class` from your local command line?

Comment: it says that there's no such file or directory

Comment: That's the problem. How are you expecting those class files to get there? If maven is building your app, it would expect the class file to be at `target/classes`. What if you run `heroku run ls target/classes/ServerMain.class`?

Comment: well the bin folder does contain the ServerMain.class when getting there with the file explorer. I don't have the classes folder. I tried to create it manually and add the class files but when I'm using the mvn clean install command it deletes the classes folder. tried without the mvn command and got same problem with the main class

Comment: How are the classes getting into the `bin` dir locally? Probably by Eclipse right? But Eclipse doesn't run your build on Heroku, Maven does. So try getting Maven to generate your class files locally. Then change your `Procfile` to contain `-cp target/classes:target/dependency/*`

Comment: thanks  a lot!! created maven projet and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

(Repeating what's in the comments so this can be marked as answered)

Make sure you're using Maven to compile the classes, then change `bin` to `target/classes` such that your `Procfile` contains this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* ServerMain
```

The classes in the bin dir were probably generated by Eclipse.